# .Net Charts are not being over written

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

I'm having some difficulty with the MSFT .Net Charts API. I want the chart images to not be deleted

```
    deleteAfterServicing=false
```

and I want them to be over written every 15 min

```
    timeout=900
```

But instead what happens is every time I load the chart it just creates a new file.
If I set deleteAfterServicing to true then the files do not persist (they are immediately deleted)

Here is my entire key

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=900;dir=D:\StatTick\tempCharts\;deleteAfterServicing=false"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you may find some help in the "Managing Images Manually", "#SEQ" section on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456629.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a limitation of the API. Either way I re-wrote this so that I generate the chart in code use .SaveImage() to save it where I want, this way I can overwrite it at whatever interval I want.